# How do I configure Astro to output separate CSS from HTML?

Tags: vite, rollupjs, astrojs

By default, in Astro, the CSS is duplicated and injected into each HTML file in a `<style>` tag. I got a very small site with a couple of pages and minimum CSS.

My CSS in mainly in a external .css file *src/style/base.css* but also inside components, that are reused across pages.

As it is now, all of the styles are inside a `<style>` element, inside the `<head>` element.
Because of that, I can not use [Astro Purgecss](https://github.com/codiume/orbit/tree/main/packages/astro-purgecss), because that only works when HTML and CSS is separated into different files.

I like having old visual effect styles laying around in my CSS, so I can quickly use them again, if needed. And I'm used to frameworks removing unused styles for my build.

**How can I get that with Astro? I only need some way to configure Astro to output a single CSS file.**

PS. PurgeCSS is not the only tool that requires HTML and CSS to be split into separate files. The same goes for [uCSS](https://github.com/oyvindeh/ucss) and [UnCSS](https://github.com/uncss/uncss).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you to solve your problem... from official documents:
https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#production

If you would rather all project styles remain external, you can configure the inlineStylesheets build option.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    inlineStylesheets: 'never'
  }
});
```